# Black screen while playing video from YouTube : Phonegap Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am playing a you tube video from a URL its playing and sounds is coming but on UI black screen is appearing only , but when i do video in Full screen mode then its visible ..my code are below please review it and guide me if and where i m wrong..

```
try{
$("#videoProdName").text(dataArr[3]+' - '+dataArr[1]);
 $("#videoProdPrice").text(dataArr[2]+" MSRP");
// $("#buyNowVideo").attr("href",dataArr[7]);
var videourl=dataArr[5]+"?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&cc_load_policy=1";

$("#youTubeVideo").html('<iframe height="200" width="100%" src="'+videourl+'"        frameborder="0" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
//  

$.mobile.changePage( "#video-page", {transition: "slide"});
    $("#aPageVideo").fadeTo("fast", .5);
}catch(e){alert("Exp: "+e)}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Phonegap YouTube's plugin to get this done:

https://github.com/remcob00/cordova-phonegap_youtube_player_api_android

Answer (score 0):

I think same issue happening in My Android Simulator, when I try to Launch the App using Tab/Phone, Video works as Expected,

If you are using PhoneGAP I advice to use HTML5 video tags for the Android Application.

Please check this Post

[html5 video player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721679/html5-video-player)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this in the config.xml file inside the res folder:

```
<feature name="VideoPlayer">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer" />  
</feature>
```

NOT videoplayer... VideoPlayer....
NOT `<param name="VideoPlayer"... <param name="android-package"...`